# Can I assign sequence number to the records in reducer

Tags: sorting, hadoop, mapreduce

I wish to assign a sequence number to the events coming from the Mapper class based on the time the events happened.

For example, I have 100 events which have a time in them. I wish to sort them based on the time and then in the reducer phase assign a sequence number to them. Also, remove the duplicate records in the reducer phase if they are duplicate (Same events happening at the same time).

Mapper method:

```
public class EventMapper extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Event> {

public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    String line = value.toString();
    Text newKey;
    Event e = new Event();
    e.setAllValues(line);
    newKey = new Text(e.getKey());
    context.write(newKey, e);
}
}
```

Reducer Method (Something what I wish for):

```
public class EventReducer extends Reducer<Text, Event, Text, Text> {

public void reduce(Text key, Iterator<Event> itrtr, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    Event e;
    List<Event> l = new ArrayList<Event>();
    while(itrtr.hasNext()){
        e = itrtr.next();
         l.add(e);
    }
    Collections.sort(l);
    long i = 1;
    for (Event event : l) {
        event.setId(++i);
        context.write(key, new Text(event.toString()));
    }
}
}
```

I get all the ids as 0. How can I achieve this? Am I following a wrong approach.

Here is the Event class:

```
public class Event implements Writable, WritableComparable<Event> {
//Some variables and getter + setters
 @Override
public String toString() {
    String delimiter1 = "|";
    return this.date + delimiter1
            + this.evName + delimiter1
            + this.evType + delimiter1
            + this.evValue + delimiter1
            + this.name + delimiter1
            + this.id;
}

@Override
public void readFields(DataInput in) throws IOException {
    try {
        this.date = converStringToDate((WritableUtils.readString(in)).toString(), dateFormat);
    } catch (ParseException ex) {
        System.out.println("Wront date . Pe");
    }
    this.evName = WritableUtils.readString(in);
    this.evType = WritableUtils.readString(in);
    this.evValue = WritableUtils.readString(in);
    this.name = WritableUtils.readString(in);
    this.id = WritableUtils.readVLong(in);
}

@Override
public void write(DataOutput out) throws IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    WritableUtils.writeString(out, this.convertDateToString(date));
    WritableUtils.writeString(out, evName);
    WritableUtils.writeString(out, evType);
    WritableUtils.writeString(out, evValue);
    WritableUtils.writeString(out, name);
    WritableUtils.writeVLong(out, id);
}

public int compareTo(Event o) {
    long value = this.getDate().getTime() - o.getDate().getTime();
    if (value == 0) {
        return 0;
    } else if (value > 1) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
    }
public void setAllValues(String input) {
    String[] arrValues = input.split(delimiter);
    System.out.println("No of Values = " + arrValues.length);
    try {
        this.date = converStringToDate(arrValues[0], dateFormat);
    } catch (ParseException pe) {
        System.out.println("pe> Error in date");
    }
    if (arrValues.length >= 2) {
        this.evName = arrValues[1];
    }
    if (arrValues.length >= 3) {
        this.evType = arrValues[2];
    }
    if (arrValues.length >= 4) {
        this.evValue = arrValues[3];
    }
    if (arrValues.length >= 5) {
        this.name = arrValues[4];
    }
}

public String getKey() {
    //return convertDateToString(this.date) + this.evName + this.evType;
    return this.evName;
}
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for class Event, or if it's not your class can you post the fully qualified name?  Is Event a hadoop Writable?

Comment: @Chris Added the Event class code here

Comment: Thanks. And where is the setAllValues(String) method source?

Comment: Added. I might have done some misplaced brackets, but please ignore those.

Comment: Sorry to be nickeling and diming you to death, but can you post the complete source for the reduce() method?

Comment: This is done @Chris . I have added both Mapper and Reducer methods. I have nerves of steel considering you could solve this problem :)

Answer (score 0):

A couple of suggestions:

- Change getKey() to return the date.getTime().  That's a long value and is faster to compare than strings.  Change your inner key type to LongWritable.
- You are exploiting the hadoop behavior of sorting records by key value before being passed to the reducer.  That's one way to sort, but you have to be sure to set numberOfReducers to 1 in your job configuration.  Otherwise you'll have multiple reducers assigning ranks on their own partitions starting at 1.
- You could go with more than one reducer, but you'd have to follow this job with a job to merge all of the internally-ranked data partitions.
- Remember that your reducer will be called once for each key value, even if there are multiple records with that key (e.g. multiple events at the same time).  If you want to ignore these duplicate events then the reducer should only write one record to the context regardless of how many records the `Iterable` value has.
- In order to assign the rank (id) correctly, you'll need to have an instance variable in your reducer of type long (call it `counter`).  You'll need to initialize it in the `setup()` method and increment it in the `reduce()` method.

Comment: Could you share some code which I can use directly as I have already tried many options based on your suggestion and I always get 0 in the file. Seeting time as the key will be misleading as two different events can happen at the same time. so evName and evType has to be part of the key.

Comment: Are the classes as posted up to date and are these all of your classes?